# How to start a new activity and start a method in that activity

Tags: java, android

So I'm working with Java in android studio and I want to start a new class from a different class (I'm in `ListenerServiceFromWear` and want to start `MainActivity`) and once `Mainactivity` is started I want to start a method (`startEmergencyMode();`) in `Mainactivity`.

How do I do this from `ListenerServiceFromWear`?

Comment: ``MainActivity ma = new MainActivity(); ma.startEmergencyMode();`` ?

Comment: I tried that but it gives an error with view.findById() because it's looking in the listener.java file when It's supposed to be looking in MainActivity. That's why I thought that I was maybe calling a method from another java file instead of actually starting the mainactivity file and then call the method

Answer (score 1):

Start `MainActivity` with an intent and in the extra of the intent put some flag that will tell `MainActivity` to call `startMergencyMode()`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Mainactivity.class);
intent.putExtra("isEmergency", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

And then in `Mainactivity` actually call `startEmergencyMode()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ...

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    boolean isEmergency = intent.getBooleanExtra("isEmergency", false);

    if(isEmergency){
        startEmergencyMode();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. But by starting the intent I get the error: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.my_emergency.samdesmedt.my_emergency.MainActivity

Comment: @hxwtch It may the same problem as  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830205/application-crash-with-android-app-application-cannot-be-cast-to)

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you mean by "start"

In java, you either:

- Declare a `static` field or method
- Create an instance of an object and use its `public` fields and methods.

If you wish to just have one 'instance' of `MainActivity`, use a static method:

```
public static void startEmergencyMode() {
    // Code here
}
```

Which you can call anywhere using `MainActivity.startEmergencyMode()`.
Keep in mind that this static method can only access static fields and other static methods.

If you wish to create an instance of `MainActivity`, simply create one and call the method:

```
public void startEmergencyMode() {
    // Code here
}


// Somewhere else
MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();
activity.startEmergencyMode();
```

If you don't understand the difference between a static and non static method or field, refer the answer on this thread: [What does 'public static void' mean in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390063/what-does-public-static-void-mean-in-java)

Comment: This works but if I do this it doesn't find the view elements because I'm working in a different java class. I thought I'd maybe have to start the activity first with an intent and then call the method?

Comment: I'm not an adroid developer but I'm guessing `ListenerServiceFromWear` is a class you made? If so, from where? If it's made from `MainActivity`, just pass the instance of `MainActivity` in the constructor of `ListenerServiceFromWear` using `this`, and then use that object to call the method on

Comment: If you do it like that, the activity will not be in android's loop. So the lifecycle events will not be called.